# TYPO3 Image Viewhelper to set Watermark on FAL Images

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, view-helpers

Is there any extension or viewhelper available which sets a watermark on a given FAL object? Currently I use compositeImage() of nativ \Imagick Object to do this, which is not  a really clean solution.

Comment: Try [this](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/tgm_copyright) extension may be helpful to you

Comment: I guess this is not what I am searching for. I want to watermark an FAL image Object . In the given EXT the copyright informations are added to html output but not on the  generated image.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can build your own viewhelper based on typoscript.
There are a lot of solutions to insert watermarks into images with typoscript.

Your 'viewhelper' call could be:

```
<f:cObject typoscritpObjectPath="lib.watermark" data="{image}" />
```

while the typoscript looks like this:

```
lib.watermark = GIFBUILDER
lib.watermark {

    // use the current image. this might need some adaption
    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
        file = current
        treatIdAsReference = 1
    }

    // add some text
    20 = TEXT
    20 {      
        text = © Name
        fontSize = 30
        fontColor = #F78F1E
        offset = [10.w]-[20.w]-10,[10.h]-10
    }

    //   add an overlay image
    30 = IMAGE
    30.file = EXT:site_ext/Resources/Private/img/watermark.png
    30.mask = EXT:site_ext/Resources/Private/img/watermark.png

    XY = [10.w],[10.h]
}
```

Comment: I know there is a TS and Gifbuilder way to do this.
However I will need tis feature for an image gallery. Therefore caching, watermarking etc. should be done more generic in the viewhelper. I found a new feature: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/61088
May I can implement it...